# Issue while rendering useEffect in React

Tags: react-hooks

I am using useEffect hook for displaying alert message in my application but when the token refreshes in 4 to 5 minutes the useEffect is not calling properly.

I using the method in this way
React.useEffect(() => {

```
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dependency array is empty which tells react to only run it on the first render. You need to add some state in it that will trigger the useEffect. Something like this would do:

```
const [tokenRefresh,setTokenRefresh]=useState(false);
```

You can change this state whenever you detect a token refresh:

```
setTokenRefresh((prev)=>!prev)
```

Then finally you can put it in your useEffect:

```
useEffect(()=>{},[tokenRefresh])
```

Answer (score 0):

The dependency array (the `[]` of `useEffect(() => { /*...*/ }, [])`) lists all the dependencies of the effect. That is all values that the effect depend on that might change, this can be states, props or constants defined in the component.

If you want an effect to run when a value changes, you need to make sure that value is listed in the dependency array.